# WPF - How to get value from child window to parent window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have 2 windows Parent window - Window_Products and Child window -  Window_NewProduct

1)In my Window_Products

- I have a list ObservableCollection ProductsList in this window which displays a list of products
- AddNewProduct() is used to add new product to the list from child window

  ```
  public AddNewProduct()
  {
       Window_NewProduct  newProduct = new Window_NewProduct();
       if(newProduct.ShowDialog() = true)
       {
             ProductsList.Add(//what code should I write here);
        }
   }
  ```

2)In my Window_NewProduct

- This window uses a user control ProductUserControl since I use the user control as a Page as well as Window

  ```
  <Window>
         <local:ProductUserControl x:Name="ProductUserControl">
   </Window>
  ```

3)In my product user control

```
public ProductUserControl()
{
        this.DataContext = new ProductViewModel();
}
```

4)In my ProductViewModel

- I have this object Product that stores the values like Prod_Name,Prod_Code in it.
- What I want is this object Product to be returned to the parent window(Window_Products) after I save the product into database so that I can add new product to the observable collection above.
- How can my object return back from the view model through the usercontrol,child window and then reach parent window.

Help me around this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new constructor for the indow_NewProduct:

```
public ProductUserControl(ProductViewModel model):base()
{
    this.DataContext = model;
}
```

In your example :
1)In my Window_Products becomes:

```
var myPVM = new ProductViewModel();

Window_NewProduct  newProduct = new Window_NewProduct(myPVM);
if(newProduct.ShowDialog() = true)
{
   ProductsList.Add(myPVM.<THE NEW PRODUCT PROPERTY YOU WILL WRITE>);
}
```

A couple of things:
1. This is not good, but it may fit your needs:
2. Take a look at MVVM and MVC, combine them to also have controlers.
3. In WPF you should try as much as possible to use the DataContext to move your data arround, this NewProduct could be part of the prant's window data context.

Answer (score 0):

Add a dependency property for your user control and bind to that in the xaml as below.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ProductProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Product", typeof(ProductDto), typeof(ProductUserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

public ProductDto Product
{
    get { return (ProductDto)this.GetValue(ProductProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(ProductProperty, value); }
}

<TextBox Margin="2" Text="{Binding Path=Product.Code, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<TextBox Margin="2" Text="{Binding Path=Product.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

You should have a Product property for your Window_NewProduct's view model

```
public class Window_NewProductViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private ProductDto product;

    public ProductDto Product
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.product; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            if (value != this.product)
            {
                this.product = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Then in the Window_NewProduct xaml you should bind this property to the usercontrols dependency property

```
<local:ProductUserControl x:Name="ProductUserControl" Product="{Binding Product}"/>
```

Add parameter to the Window_NewProduct constructor that takes in the ProductDto and passes that to the ViewModel.

```
public Window_NewProduct(ProductDto product)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = new Window_NewProductViewModel() { Product = product };
}
```

Then in your MainWindow you can just create a new productDto to pass on to the DetailsWindow.

```
var newProduct = new ProductDto();

var window_NewProduct = new Window_NewProduct(newProduct);

if (window_NewProduct.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(newProduct.Code);
    Debug.WriteLine(newProduct.Name);
}
```

Comment: I get a XamlParseException when I run it

Comment: <loca:ProductUserControl Product="{Binding Product}"/>

Comment: I am getting Product property after adding dependency Property but the Product Binding thing is causing an exception

Comment: You need to add the the Product property also to the viewmodel for the Window_NewProduct, and no viewmodel for the usercontrol.

Comment: K that got cleared too but new error in second block of your code

Comment: If I use a new class for Window_NewProduct view model then there is error at SetValue property bcoz there is no such property in it

Comment: You need to implement the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx interface to do the this.SetValue thing in your viewmodel. I am just inheriting a custom viewmodel class that implements it and i'm using the method in the setter.

Comment: If I put that block  in code behind file xaml.cs then it shows invalid arguments error at  setvalue

Comment: Ok, I edited the second block so there should be no errors, you might need to add some using statement for the CallerMemberNameAttribute.

Comment: K everything is running but after I add a new product to the database from child window Window_NewProduct and then on closing the window the newProduct is null in parent window